# pip installed websockets but still getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets' "

Tags: python, websocket, pip

I am importing websockets into my project:

```
import websockets
```

have installed websockets using pip but am still getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling websockets and clearing cache using pip
using python 3.10.2, VsCode

Comment: Are you using the correct env when running the code? Have you tried running python in the terminal and importing it there?

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your system.  `pip` installed the websockets module for one version of Python, but you're running the code with a different version.